# Xcode standalone app issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, quicktime

My iMac is partitioned with OSX 10.6.8 running xCode 4.0.2 on one side (that I always use) and 10.10.3 on the other. I'm happy with my current compiler version because it works for what I need to do.

I built a handy 32-bit app strictly for personal use, but I can't get a standalone version out of the compiler and onto my desktop due to a string of errors. My frameworks are:

```
    QuickTime.framework
    QTKit.framework
    Cocoa.framework
```

(in Other Frameworks folder)

```
    AppKit.framework
    CoreData.framework
    Foundation.framework
```

In header file:

```
    #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
    #import <QTKit/QTKit.h>
    #import <QuickTime/QuickTime.h>
```

… which is followed later on by the definition:

```
    -(Track)getSubtitlesTrack;
```

Everything runs without any issues in the compiler but when I try to 'build for archiving' I get an error on above line saying "Parse Issue. Expected a Type".

In my implementation file, this method and half a dozen others that use any kind of QT data (like nextTimeTrackEdit or nextTimeMediaSample etc) give "use of undeclared identifier" failures. The code for this method is:

```
    //#########################################################
    // Returns the appropriate QT track indicated by track pop-up button
    -(Track)getSubtitlesTrack
    {
        int popUpIndex = [trackPopUpButton indexOfSelectedItem];

        NSArray *videoTracks = [refMovie tracksOfMediaType:QTMediaTypeVideo];
        QTTrack *tcTrack = [videoTracks objectAtIndex:popUpIndex];
        Track theTrack = tcTrack.quickTimeTrack;

        return theTrack;    
    }
```

Of course, I read that if I tried to build a 64-bit version I'll have even more trouble with the QuickTime frameworks (in fact I tried doing this too and it won't even compile at all) but I don't use Yosemite except for some apps that won't run in Snow Leopard anyways.

I'm not an experienced programmer and too old to grasp the technicalities of it all. So, can anyone please tell me where I might be going wrong with this?

Comment: ..... sorry my OCD forced me to comment. its "Xcode", not "xCode"

Comment: __OFF__ @SimonMcLoughlin, it s funny to say that, but there's news portal which refers Apple's devices or services like "Iphone, Itunes, Icloud" every time etc... the readers sent feedback them many times about that is _NOT_ the correct spelling, and the portal's official answer was _"stop telling us what the correct spelling would be, we don't care! there is no such word where we put capital letters in the middle of the word, and we are really sensitive to write our articles using the correct grammar"_... lol. __ON__

Comment: @holex please don't link me to that portal, I fear my poor brain couldn't handle such a traumatic experience

Comment: __OFF__ @SimonMcLoughlin, I have stopped visiting them after that arrogant feedback. I won't advertise them at all! __ON__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat: I haven't worked with Xcode in a while so I'm not quite sure about the details.

That said, creating an archived version of the application initiates a release build. Conversely, when you run the application directly from the IDE you're getting a debug build.

What is probably happening is that your debug build is configured properly with all the necessary frameworks. Your release build, however, isn't, hence the errors. What could also be happening is that some of your include/library directories are misconfigured in release mode.

This will hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: After a weekend of gOogling :-) I discovered some reports that Xcode v4 wasn't always loading the required movies.h header located in QuickTime.framework (or giving false compiler errors). No definitive fixes found ... except that some of them later reported: "I dunno what I did but suddenly it's working okay again." Guess I'll just keep fiddling. Thanks Dan, I appreciate your input.